# Можно ли на 4-м Бутстрап реализовать такую сетку?

Tags: css3, html5, bootstrap

Можно ли "штатными" возможностями 4 бутстрап реализовать такую разметку? Если да, то как?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.2.1/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
  
    <div class="col-7">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">1</div>
        <div class="col-12">2</div>
        <div class="col-12">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-5">4</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: С обертыванием то все понятно, можно ли сделать без обертывания - вот в чем вопрос.